# Freelance work and possible conflict of interest with day job

Tags: work-environment, freelancing

I am in sticky situation where I need advice on whether to accept or decline a freelance project.

I have been a approached by another coworker to development on a project. He explained to me how the application would work and what work is required to to be done.

The coworker wants the application developed so he can sell the services to various businesses including the company were we both work .
A few weeks later my supervisor asked me to manage the technical development portion of a project to create an application that is intended to solve the same problem that co worker's application is to solve.

I initial assume that this type of work is not within my normal duties, which is why I considered to work on my coworker's application.

So far I have not made any agreements ,signed any contracts or accept any payment for the work on the coworkers application. The only work don so far is gathering requirements.

Based on this situation everything tells me to decline the coworkers project and focus on the project given to me at work.

What steps should I take to ensure there will be no conflict with my employer?

Comment: What does your contract say?

Comment: My contract does not explicitly forbid me from doing work on the side,but  managing the system that application is to be integrated is one of my core job responsibilities.

Comment: The original quesiton really was not in scope of the site since it was really asking for opinions.  I have reworded the question to ask you can do to ensure there is no conflict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stick with the project at work, don't mess with the job on the side. Sounds like your co-worker 'jumped the gun' - he could see the need before management did, but the need was there and management eventually saw it.  Therefore, the only thing to do is stay within the system, and suggest to your co-worker to drop the idea.

If you're freelancing for someone in a completely unrelated line of business that has nothing to do with your current job you're in relatively clean air.  Trying to develop something to sell to your own employer is a conflict, and having a co-worker inviting you to work on it creates even more problems - now you have two conflicts of interest, one with your employer and one with your co-worker.  Either of these could get you fired, both nearly assures it.